# How to keep on watch the files inside directory is modified or not?

Tags: linux, python

I want to check the files inside the directory whether it is modified or not.If the files are modified then i need the details like (Usename, MOdified time) of that files.

Is there any tools or scripts is available for this job ?

Comment: You could use [inotify](https://linux.die.net/man/7/inotify) to watch changes in filesystem, but I don't know if it supports reporting details you specified.

Comment: Do you need a real-time notification of changes? Can a nightly batch be sufficient?

Answer (score 0):

`tripwire` is a security tool to check if files on systems have been tampered. I don't know if it is too much for your needs but it can do what you want.